Youtube Spam Classifier - Different Methods yielding the same accuracy (94%)
(CONTEXT)
I'm currently doing a report project at my university to build a classifer model that classifies a comment as spam or ham (non-spam) using this data set, and then submit a prediction csv onto Kaggle. The data is split into about 68% for training, and the rest 32% for testing. Note that as students, we were given the labels for our training and do not have access to the labels for the testing data set. Regarding pre-processing, I only performed stemming.
My report focuses on comparing different character n-grams, frequency-based text embeddings, and model combination. Specifically, we're comparing models with:

Character n-gram from 1 to 6
Text embeddings: TF-IDF vs. Bag of Words (BoW)
Models: Naive Bayes, Random Forest, Support Vector Machine (SVM)

QUESTION
My confusion comes from two things:

First, while my models consistently perform above 95% for stratified 10-fold cross-validation, when assessed for accuracy in the testing dataset, the accuracy drops to only about 93-94%. This is consistent across all my models, as the CV always yielded higher accuracy than test accuracy; What could be the issue? It seems that my data is currently overfitting. How could I resolve this?
Another point of concern is that for some odd reason, the test accuracy across many of my "best" models are the same. Here, "best" refers to highest CV accuracy. Specifically, I found that Random Forest and SVM models that use BoW for n-grams of 3 and 4 all got the same test accuracy, despite having different CV accuracy. What could be the cause of this?


Suppose many "good models" with reasonable hyperparameters are going to perform at around 93-94% accuracy on the test data just because most of the test data is easily classifiable and the rest is just a guess.  What you have done is run these models through cross-validation and trained their hyperparameters, and then chosen those which perform best in the particular cross-validation by luck when compared to other models or hyperparameters which could have done roughly as well on the test data.
